# how to get notification (broadcast, intent) on browser download completion in android

Tags: android, browser, download, notifications, broadcast

how to be notified (via some broadcast or intent) on a completion of a download initiated by user from web browser and other apps? (like email client, bluetooth, etc).
I need this as I want to perform some action on each newly file downloaded by the user.
It seems to me that this *is* possible as some antivirus apps do similar things.
I tried to use broadcast receiver with intent filter set to DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE action, but this way I get notified only about downloads from my own app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to be notified (via some broadcast or intent) on a completion of a download initiated by user from web browser and other apps? (like email client, bluetooth, etc).

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: I think it _is_ possible as some antivirus apps do similar things. Also if it is not possible then I wouldn't call this a fortunate situation: I'd expect some permission to perform such actions.

Comment: @morgwai: "I think it is possible as some antivirus apps do similar things" -- you are welcome to your opinion. They are not being notified "via some broadcast or intent". "I wouldn't call this a fortunate situation" -- once again, you are welcome to your opinion. However, you have no authority to force all Android developers worldwide to adhere to your demands. Any app is welcome to perform Internet operations (given the `INTERNET` permission); such apps are not required to tell other developers about them.

Comment: I don't think I made any demand to any android devs in my question, did I?  anyway... if you do know that such antivirus apps are not notified by via broadcast nor intent maybe you know of some other mechanism to achieve this? Please also note that such capability (being notified on new content appearing on the sdcard) is virtually equivalent to capability of reading content on sdcard from the security and privacy point of view: to create an app that steals downloaded content one could just scan sdcard from time to time.

Comment: @morgwai: "I don't think I made any demand to any android devs in my question, did I?" -- you expect all apps to do something to enable your app to find out about all downloads "via some broadcast or intent". That constitutes a demand IMHO.

Comment: @morgwai: "being notified on new content appearing on the sdcard" -- "downloads" does not imply "external storage" (a.k.a., "sdcard"). A running application can monitor file I/O on external storage via `FileObserver`. You have no means of reliably determining what or who caused the file I/O (e.g., a "download" or not). This also does not cover downloads that are not delivered to external storage. Hence, `FileObserver` is full of false positives and false negatives to determine "download initiated by user from web browser and other apps".

Comment: I'm sorry if didn't make myself clear enough previously: I don't expect all apps to do sth to enable other parties to find out about all their downloads. That would be stupid of course. Instead I would suppose that there may be a mechanism in android system to let interested parties know when something is downloaded via system services like DownloadService.   Many thanks for the hint about FileObserver! As you wrote it has some drawbacks, but it will be probably sufficient for my needs if there's no better way to do this. Thanks again!